# How to link SVG files to Inkscape?

Tags: macos, mac, install, macports

I installed `Inkscape-0.48.3.1` via MacPorts to my Mac OS X 10.9.1 System. I Can start it from the Terminal using the command `inkscape`, which starts inkscape fomr the location `/opt/local/bin/inkscape`.

How can I link Inkscape to SVG files? I'd really like to open SVG-files by double clicking on the file.

When installed via Macports, Inkscape does not appear in the drop-down of the "open with" dialog. An entry is only added, when I install Inkscape using the installer from the Inkscape website. The problem is, that this version does not run properly under Mavericks (10.9.1). Sor far I could not find a way the this location to the dropdown menu or add a launcher to the panel.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question:

If you control-click (right-click) on an SVG file, select "Get Info" from the menu.  A window will open, with several sections.  One is "Open with:".  You may need to click the triangle next to it, but you should see a selector where you can choose the program which should open the file when it is double-clicked.

[image]

Since you want the same behavior for all .SVG files, press the "Change All..." button, and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Inkscape only appears in the drop-down menu, when I install it using the installer from the inkscape website. The problem is, that this version does not run properly under Mavericks (10.9.1). Thus I installed Inkscape using Macports, which adds Inkscape to `/opt/local/bin/inkscape`. I could not find a way the this location to the dropdown menu or add a launcher to the panel.

Comment: If you click "Other..." at the bottom of the drop-down, a standard open-file dialog window opens.  Even if you can't navigate to the folder, you can press command+shift+g and type in `/opt/local/bin` where the inkscape binary should be.  Another option (but, less elegant) would be to make an alias or unix link from the `/Applications/` folder to the macports binary.  Off-topic; but, thanks for the heads-up about Inkscape+10.9 -- I was just about ready to install it on all the computers at my office.